# Как заставить QVariant::value() возвратить QMap<QString, QVariant> для кастомного контейнерного типа?

Tags: c++, qt, преобразование-типов

Для удобство давайте пользоваться типом `VariantMap`, таким что:

```
typedef QMap<QString, QVariant> VariantMap;
```

(это преамбула). Итак:

1. Определяю некоторый кастомный контейнерный тип `ArgContainer`
2. Регистрирую с помощью `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE`:

   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ArgContainer)
3. Регистрирую с помощью `qRegisterMetaType`
4. Определяю и описываю в классе `ArgContainer`:

   operator VariantMap();

В результате:

```
//(далее в примере используется QVariant value с данными ArgContainer)
//1. Вот так работает правильно
{
ArgContainer ac = value.value<ArgContainer>();
VariantMap vm = (VariantMap)ac;
}

//2. А вот так возвращает пустой массив:
{
VariantMap vm = value.value<VariantMap>();
}
//(так дает синтаксическу ошибку VariantMap vm = (VariantMap)value)
```

---

Минимальный работающий пример полностью и в одном файле:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <QDebug>

typedef QMap<QString, QVariant> VariantMap;

class ArgContainer1
{
public:
    operator VariantMap() {
        return QMap<QString, QVariant>({{"test","hey"}});
    }
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(ArgContainer1)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    ArgContainer1 ac0;
    QVariant value = QVariant::fromValue<ArgContainer1>(ac0);
    //1. Вот так работает правильно
    {
    ArgContainer1 ac = value.value<ArgContainer1>();
    VariantMap vm = (VariantMap)ac;
    qDebug() << "1 value:" << vm.value("test");
    }

    //2. А вот так возвращает пустой массив:
    {
    VariantMap vm = value.value<VariantMap>();
    qDebug() << "2 value:" << vm.value("test");
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Результат выполнения в консоле:

> ```
> 1 value: QVariant(QString, "hey")
> 2 value: QVariant(Invalid)
> ```

---

**Вопрос, что сделать с типом `ArgContainer`, чтобы заработал вариант (2)?**
**То есть, правильно заработала функция QVariant::value() для `ArgContainer`**

Comment: Приведите полный, минимальный пример, чтобы тем, кто захочет Вам помочь не пришлось сочинять свой.

Comment: @ixSci Да, спасибо за замечание, добавил

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Чтобы решить задачу, нужно одно изменение и одна регистрация.

Изменение: нужно сделать оператор преобразования константным (так надо было сделать сразу, ведь по уму он и должен быть таким).

```
operator VariantMap() const {
    return QMap<QString, QVariant>({{"test","hey"}});
}
```

Регистрация: нужно сообщить метасистеме Qt, что у нас есть конвертация между типами (где-нибудь в main, к примеру).

```
QMetaType::registerConverter<ArgContainer1, VariantMap>();
```

Comment: Ответ просто Супер! Спасибо!